# Jquery animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, dos

I have a set of buttons 0-9, and I have some jQuery animating them when the mouse hovers over them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#1").fadeTo("slow",.8);
    });
    $("#1").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#1").fadeTo("slow",1)
    });
  });
```

Is there a way i can implement this code to all ten buttons without having to copy and paste this nine times?

Comment: give all your buttons same class

Comment: @adeneo yeah i meant mouseleave

Comment: @JamesCrovo Can you kindly see my answer?

Comment: @praveenkumar yes i did thank you :)

Comment: @JamesCrovo Does it work for you?

Comment: @praveenkumar http://ac.net.co/projects/calculator/calculator.html

Comment: @JamesCrovo Try to combine the selector like how I did. Check my answer. Use something like this: `}).mouseout(function(){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a same `class` for all and reference the respective object using `this`. Also change it to `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sameclass").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).fadeTo("slow",.8);
   }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).fadeTo("slow",1)
   });
});
```

And seeing your code, it is not a good practise to use `just numbers` like `id="1"` in giving `ID`s.